# How can I configure Meteor to use Amazon SES when running on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, smtp, meteor, amazon-ses

I would like to use the built in email methods that Meteor provides, but I need my app to run on Heroku and use the smtp endpoint of Amazon SES to transport my message.

I'm using the Meteorite build pack and the accounts-password package.

Comment: waiting for time limit to answer my own question - until then, answer is here https://gist.github.com/4560017

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Follow instructions below to get meteor emails sending correctly from heroku using amazon ses

1) set up smtp access via aws console, get your smtp credentials

2) using a javascript console (chrome dev tools / firebug) run

`encodeURIComponent("SES_SMTP_USERNAME")`

`encodeURIComponent("SES_SMTP_PASSWORD")`

to encode the username/password for use in your smtp url

3) take resulting strings to build your smtp url like so

`smtp://ENCODED_USER:ENCODED_PASS@SES_SMTP_URL:465`

4) set the MAIL_URL variable to tell meteor to use this method for sending emails

`heroku config:add MAIL_URL=YOUR_SMTP_URL`

(do not surrond the url with qoutes)

5) set sender to be a SES verified sender within your meteor app via

`Accounts.emailTemplates.from = "SENDER_NAME <SENDER_EMAIL>";`

---

That will allow Meteor default email methods to function properly.

Comment: I also made a package that does it all using aws credentials, including from Email.send

Comment: I had to change the protocol to smtps for this to work

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what you've suggested in your gist you could also use `Meteor.http` methods with SES API and send a POST/GET request.

Full API docs at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/QueryInterface.Examples.html

Of course this is a manual solution, and wont use the built in meteor mail method. It can however be corrected by redefining the mail function via `Email.send = function(...`

#### UPDATE

You can also use the email-ses package on atmosphere

```
mrt add email-ses
```

More info here: https://atmospherejs.com/package/email-ses

Comment: true - could even use an npm module like https://npmjs.org/package/node-ses to avoid having to manually interact with the API - still doesnt quite give the native 'it just works' feeling that setting ses as smtp server does

Comment: + the smtp server gets the dkim issue sorted out

Comment: @Aaron thanks for reminding me, I did update it but Meteor was still in beta and hadn't yet made atmosphere public. I'll try and sort it out by tomorrow. Sorry :(

Comment: @Akshat, wow that's great!  Do you mind if I somehow check back with you on this or maybe if you want to answer my SO question with your new package?  Also, will your package incorporate the newer 1.* version of  adris9/Nodemailer & andris9/nodemailer-ses-transport ?

Comment: @Aaron I just pushed up a version, I need to work on the docs and to bring it up to 1.*, at the moment is uses the mrt:nodemailer package. I'm not too sure what version it uses, but ill update the `tarang:email-ses` to use the latest one a bit later tomorrow. For the moment i've made one that works now with this answer, just its `meteor add tarang:ses` instead

Comment: @Akshat, I tried your package but it's not working on my EC2 instance.  My SO question about your package setup and use is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058641/aws-ses-with-meteor-and-the-tarangemail-ses-package